# Android, Xamarin: How to make absolutely sure that a user gets delted once the app is destroyed?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

I have a bit of a problem:

I am working on an instant chat application for android where I need to make sure that a user gets deleted from the database as soon as he or she closes the app. There is this line of code:

```
Firebase.Instance.CurrentUser.Delete();
```

Which deletes the current user. I could put a LogOut button and have this line integrated into the Onclick Event which will delete the user from the database. But chances are that peeps won't click that button but instead just close the app from the taskmanager. (Or maybe their phone runs out of battery?)

Well, the problem is obvious: I cannot have more than 100 users connected to my server ( for monetary reasons), so it is vital for me to have the user and all of his records deleted upon closure of the app.

My next thought was to put the above line of code into the OnDestroy() Method, yet I came to realize that this method is sometimes not called and also doesn't seem to be able to delete the user even when called (Maybe it is too much work? I don't know).

What else could I be trying?

Comment: according to documentation `onPause()` is the final method which will definitely be called even if app is force closed ,so write your method inside `onPause()`

Comment: hello and thank you. As far as my knowledge goes - on Pause will always be called when the app is send into the background, right? So in that case - when a user stores the app in the background his or her user will get deleted right? That could be a problem because Im sure people may want to go back to the app ... But this mmight be the only solotion ..

Comment: If you can not solve it at the app side move it over to the server? For example the server can have a "keep-alive"-timer. Is the timer expired delete the user. Every time the user uses the current session, the time will be reset and starts again when the user becomes inactive.

Comment: what if user disconnects from internet while using your app ?

Comment: thats a good idea tequila slammer. Im using the free plan on firebase. I dont thing that exists there but i shall find out about it. And mr Redman, I dont know what happens if the user disconnects from the internet it probabbly chrases then... xD

Comment: You are solving the imaginary problem. You cannot have more than 100 users connected to the Firebase at same moment, but you can have more than 100 users. You don't need to delete users, you need to detach all observers in onPause() and that is all.

Comment: Ok thanks that is a good thinking!

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That sounds like a great answer. Feel like posting it, so MrMee can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving imaginary problem. You cannot have more than 100 users actively connected to the Firebase at the same moment, but you can have more than 100 users.

You don't need to delete users, you need to detach all observers in `onPause()` and that is all.